# javascript rounding

Tags: javascript

I want to round `TheCount / 5` to the next highest integer. When `TheCount = 12`

I tried:

```
Math.round(TheCount / 5);
```

but it returns 2 and I need it to return 3.

How does rounding to the next highest integer work?

Thanks.

Comment: What type of rounding are you trying to perform? 12 / 5 = 2.4, and most people would say that round(2.4) = 2 is correct.

Comment: @PhilipSheard: I'm using this to count the number of pages. So 12 items with 5 items per pages is 3 pages.

Comment: Then in plain English you are rounding up, not rounding. You want the ceil function, as everyone suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ceil function rounds up.

```
Math.ceil( TheCount / 5 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

Answer (score 1):

Rounding up can be done with [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Answer (score 1):

I think [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

rather than Math.round you want Math.ceil

So you'd want

var result = Math.ceil(TheCount / 5);

Hope that helps!